# Android and new JSON in my old app

Tags: android, json

I wrote an application that retrieves data from WebService and show these in ListView.

This is my JSON object:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": "240",
        "title": "Przemys\u0142 stoczniowy. Co dalej?",
        "introtext": "<p>Przemys\u0142 stoczniowy prze\u017cywa obecn[....]"
    }, {
        "id": "239",
        "title": "Ceny Franka \u2013 prognozy",
        "introtext": "</p><p>Po ostatnich zmianach w kursie Franka wiele [...]"
    }, {
        "id": "238",
        "title": "Otwarty Fundusz Emerytalny",
        "introtext": "</p><p>Saldo zakup\u00f3w i sprzeda\u017cy akcji [...]"
    }, {
        "id": "233",
        "title": "Czy waluta Bitcoin doczeka\u0142a si\u0119 gro\u017anego konkurenta?",
        "introtext": "</p><p>Bitcoin - kryptowaluta, wprowadzona w 2009 roku. [...]"
    }],
    "success": 1
}
```

and these is my static variables - JSON Node names:

```
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String TAG_PID = "id";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "title";
public static final String TAG_INTROTEXT = "introtext";
```

And these work fine.

Now I have different JSON:

```
{"status":200,
"data":
{"slide":[
{"image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/slide\/1.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/product?id=52\x0078lang=pl"},
{"image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/slide\/2.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/product?id=53\x0078lang=pl"},
{"image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/slide\/3.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/product?id=4\x0078lang=pl"},
{"image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/slide\/4.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/product?id=13\x0078lang=pl"}],
"portfolio":[
{"id":52,"name":"Aplikacja pierwsza","description":"To jest opis aplikacji pierwszej[...]"},
{"id":37,"name":"Aplikacja druga","description":"To jest opis aplikacji drugiej [...]"},
{"id":4,"name":"Aplikacja trzecia","description":"To jest opis aplikacji trzeciej [...]"},
{"id":51,"name":"Aplikacja czwarta","description":"To jest opis aplikacji czwartej [...]"},
"person":[
{"name":"Jan Kowalski","position":"Prezes","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/persons\/1.png"},
{"name":"Jan Nowak","position":"Dyrektor","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/persons\/2.png"},
{"name":"Adam Malysz","position":"Vice Director","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/persons\/3.png"}],
"work":[
{"name":"Programista","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/file-type\/android.png","file":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/file\/ogloszenie_1.pdf"},
{"name":"Praktykant","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/file-type\/smarttv.png","file":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/file\/ogloszenie_2.pdf"},
{"name":"Project Manager","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/file-type\/pm.png","file":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/file\/dogloszenie_3.pdf"},
{"name":"Tester","image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/file-type\/tester.png","file":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/file\/ogloszenie_4.pdf"}
]}}
```

Now I must extract variables: id, name and description.

When I write in TAG_PRODUCTS string "portfolio", I get:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for portfolio
```

and when I write  in TAG_PRODUCTS string "data" - or more broadly, I get:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"work":[{"image":"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/image\/slide\/1.jpg"[...]
```

system gives me long JSON string in Log, but my app not working (end running in try- catch block).

Comment: Your new JSON isn't valid JSON. `portfolio` doesn't have a closing square-bracket

Comment: Also, add your Java code. Where you are parsing this JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanx!
These is solve my problem:

```
products = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("portfolio");
```

data id object-container and portfolio is Sub-array

Answer (score 0):

The array which is the value of the `porfolio` key is not closed. You must be sure that your JSON is well formed before parsing it.

Try to use a `try`-`catch` block for `JSONException` on your code, at the very beginning when you start parsing the **JSON**.